# How to reshape a tensor in Eigen3?

Tags: c++, tensor, eigen3

I get some Eigen::TensorMap from the outputs vector from a tensorflow session in C++. I want to do some operations to the Eigen::TensorMap (reshape and concat etc.).

However, my codes cannot be compiled due to some weird error. 
I tried to reproduce it in pure Eigen3 code.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
using Eigen::Tensor;
using Eigen::TensorMap;
using Eigen::TensorRef;
using std::vector;
int main() {
    int storage[128];
    TensorMap<Tensor<int, 4>> t_4d(storage, 2, 4, 2, 8);
    vector<TensorRef<Tensor<int,2>>> reshapedTensors;
    std::array<int, 2> shape{ 16,8 };
    auto re_op = t_4d.reshape(shape);
    reshapedTensors.push_back(re_op);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the [Eigen Doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html), the return type of reshape function is an eigen operation, it will be caculate lazily. The TensorRef is the wrapper of all tensor operations.

This piece of codes will complain that:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2679    binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::array' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    testEigen   D:\Programming\cpp library\eigen-eigen-323c052e1731\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\src\Tensor\TensorRef.h  49

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix different `IndexType` for Tensor operations (that is the implicit 4th template parameter of `Tensor`). This also means the type of the `std::array` must match the `IndexType`. By default, `Eigen::Tensor` uses `Eigen::DenseIndex` which is the same as `Eigen::Index`. You can either write this instead of `Eigen::Tensor<int,4>` (similar for `Tensor<int,2>`)

```
Eigen::Tensor<int, 4, 0, int>
```

or you replace `std::array<int, 2>` by `std::array<Eigen::Index, 2>`.
Of course making `typedef`s for both will safe you some typing and will simplify refactoring, if you ever need to do that.